# Access 2013 - Textbox formula producing a #Name? error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a textbox that I want to display one of 2 values - 
1. A Date
2. the word "Incomplete"

I've tested this in the immediate window and it works perfectly.

Here's my logic:
If my desired condition were true, all records would have a date, if the dates are different or if some records have no date, then it would be "Incomplete"

This can be achieved analyzing this query called SP_ALL_ACTUALS_AS_OF:

```
SELECT tbl_SP.Actuals_AsOf
FROM tbl_SP
GROUP BY tbl_SP.Actuals_AsOf;
```

If the query is my desired condition then only one record comes up - "The date" that is in every single record in the Actuals_AsOf field of tbl_SP

However, if there are blanks here and there, there will be a minimum of 2 records, one of which will not be a date.  So if I find 1 grouping that is not a date, then the entire condition should be "Incomplete"

so here is the formula in the textbox

```
IIf(DCount("[Actuals_AsOf]","SP_ALL_ACTUALS_AS_OF",IsDate([Actuals_AsOf])=False)=1,"Incomplete",Nz(DLookUp("[Actuals_AsOf]","SP_ALL_ACTUALS_AS_OF"),"Not pulled"))
```

I tested it in the immediate window and all is fine. However, when I implement this textbox on a form, I get a #Name? error.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
=IIf(DCount("*","SP_ALL_ACTUALS_AS_OF","IsDate([Actuals_AsOf])=False")=1,"Incomplete",Nz(DLookUp("[Actuals_AsOf]","SP_ALL_ACTUALS_AS_OF"),"Not pulled"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your 'formula' in the Control Source of the Textbox you have to:

1) begin your Control Source string with an equal ('=')

2) Replace all commas (',') with semi-colon (';')

You can also set your Textbox with VBA in the onCurrent eventProc or onLoad event of your form, and your formula as to be written as in your post.